# MySQL Query Displaying Multiple Comma Delimted Values from one Field Group Concat?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat

I have the following query that isn't returning the expected results.

I am trying to get all of the group names from a field, group_id, that potentially has multiple group_ids that are separated by commas (ex., 1,4,5,7,22). My original query returned only the first group listed in the list of groups_ids but did not return any group after the first comma. It returned just under 3,000 records.

To fix this, I tried using the group_concat function. It worked (no error), but it only returned one record when I was expecting close to 3,000.

I am not sure if I am using the function incorrectly or I am just missing code? If there is another function that would work better, I am all for it. Thanks in advance for your help!

My Query:

```
select `v`.`asset_id` AS `asset_id`,
`v`.`watched_on` AS `watched_on`,
`v`.`status` AS `Completed_Status`,
`va`.`asset_name` AS `asset_name`,
`u`.`fname` AS `fname`,
`u`.`lname` AS `lname`,
group_concat(distinct `g`.`name` separator ',') AS `group_name` 
from (((`vm_video_history` `v` 
join `vm_users` `u` on((`u`.`id` = `v`.`user_id`))) 
left join `vm_groups` `g` on((`g`.`group_id` = `u`.`group_id`))) 
left join `vm_assets` `va` on((`va`.`asset_id` = `v`.`asset_id`)))
order by `v`.`user_id`;
```

Comment: You probably need to add a GROUP BY.

Comment: You need a `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Are you trying to create a column in the result that has a comma-separated list, or does the table already have a comma-separated list? If it's the latter, there's no easy way to split it up and create a new distinct list. You need to normalize your schema to put the group IDs in a many-to-many relationship table.

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT` is for taking single values and aggregating them into a comma-separated list. There's no function for splitting up a comma-separated list.

Comment: It already has one. :-\

Comment: Well, it sort of does have one - with a few tricks... but it's not a great idea